# Bash comparison of two strings

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, comparison

I'm probably having a big logical mind barrier right now and i just don't get it.. I hope someone can help me.

I'm writing a script with arguments and the first argument needs to be "activate" or "deactivate" so i wrote this:

```
if [ "$1" != "activate" ] || [ "$1" != "deactivate" ]; then
   echo $1
   exit 1
fi
echo "Hello the first argument is $1"
```

so if i run now 'myscript.sh activate' the output is:

```
user@host$ ./myscript.sh activate
activate
```

but the output should be "Hello the first argument is activate"...

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong or what i need to change?

Thanks

Comment: your 1st argument which is "activate" is certainly not equal to "deactivate". Which make the second comparison set to true. Remember you are using OR operator in between.

Comment: `[ "$1" != "deactivate" ]` is true.

Comment: yeah thanks, i think i got it now:)

Comment: i know, i wanted to do that but it said i need to wait a few minutes until i'm able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
if [ "$1" != "activate" ] && [ "$1" != "deactivate" ]; then
```